# cannot return app.post to not save usermodel for multiple instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
app.post('/register', async function(req, res) {

  console.log(req.body.email)
  console.log(req.body.username)
  console.log(req.body.password)

  await userModel.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).then(
    (user)=>{
      if(user != null){
        res.send('exists');
        return;
      }
  }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });

  await userModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(
    (user)=>{
      if(user != null){
        res.send('exists');
        return;
      }
  }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });

  const userInstance = new userModel(
  {
    username: req.body.username,
    password : req.body.password,
    email: req.body.email,
    imagelink: "/images/blank",
    links: [],
    plan: 0
  });

  userInstance.save().then((savedUser) => {
        if(savedUser){ /*console.dir(savedUser, {depth:null});*/ res.send('success'); }
   }).catch((error) => {
       console.log(error);
       //res.send(400, "Bad Request");
   });

});
```

I have this code above which create and saves user to the database, yet when a user actually `exists` it should `return` after `res.send()` yet it still save the Instance to the database so I get multiple instances of the same email/username combination. how do i return for the whole function if a user exists so that I do not have same email multiple times in the DB. The `return` here seems to be NOT doing what I want.

I also get this error for the line where it has `res.send("success")`

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Comment: Have you tried `return res.send('exists');` instead?

Comment: Didn't work @jQueeny I think since I am using ```await``` return just returns that... yet I need to return the whole thing

Comment: You are mixing `await` with `then` blocks. Would you like an example of how to do this properly with `async/await`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is by adding a `unique` constraint to the `username` and `email` properties in your schema. Mongoose will then perform validation when you try to create a new user with a `username` or `email` that already exists. Your schema would look like this:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: {
      type: String,
      unique: true //< Adds a unique index
   },
   password: String,
   email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true //< Adds a unique index
   },
   imagelink: String,
   links: [String],
   plan: Number
});
```

Then in your route handler just try to create a new user and mongoose will throw an error if a user already exists with those credentials like so:

```js
app.post('/register', async function(req, res) {
   try{
      const userInstance = await userModel.create({
         username: req.body.username,
         password: req.body.password,
         email: req.body.email,
         imagelink: "/images/blank",
         links: [],
         plan: 0
      });
      return res.status(201).json({
         message: 'Successfully created.'
      });
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      if(err.code === 11000){
         return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'User already exists.'
         });
      }
      return res.status(500).json({
         message: 'Error on server.'
      });
   }
})
```

**Note**: `err.code === 11000` is the duplicate key error that mongoose throws if the `username` or `email` from `req.body` already exists in your collection. Passwords should never be stored as plain text and you should implement a pre save hook and hash your password but that's a different question.